# Length of primary component: confusion about definition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am confused about the definition of the length of a primary component given in Eisenbud-Harris's book "The geometry of schemes".  It appears on page 68.  For simplicity, let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $R = k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.  Let $I$ be an ideal in $R$ and let $p$ be an associated prime of $I$.  They define the length of the primary component of $I$ associated to $p$ to be the length of the largest ideal of finite length in the ring $R_p/I R_p$, which by definition is the maximal length of a chain of ideals terminating in that ideal.

They then claim that the length of the primary component of $(xy,y^2) \subset k[x,y]$ at the origin is $1$.  Here $p = (x,y)$, so we are looking at the length of $(k[x,y]/(xy,y^2))_{(x,y)}$.  Ideals in this ring are the same thing as ideals $I$ of $k[x,y]$ such that $(xy,y^2) \subseteq I \subseteq (x,y)$.  But we can find arbitrarly long chains of such ideals; for instance,

$$(xy,y^2) \subsetneq (x^n,xy,y^2) \subsetneq (x^{n-1},xy,y^2) \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq (x,xy,y^2) = (x,y^2) \subsetneq (x,y).$$

I thus must be confused about something.  Where is my error?

Comment: Maybe you erred when assumed that $(x,y)$ is the largest ideal which has finite length.

Comment: Ah, I see!  Playing around with it a bit, the right ideal to look at is $(y)$.  Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion this is the ideal $(x^2,y)$ (which is $(y)$ in the quotient, as you said).

Comment: Are you sure?  There are arbitrarly long chains terminating at that ideal: for $n \geq 2$, take $(x^n,y) \subsetneq (x^{n-1},y) \subsetneq (x^{n-2},y) \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq (x^2,y)$.

Comment: (maybe I just don't see why $(x^2,y)$ and $(y)$ are the same modulo $(xy,y^2)$)

Comment: The quotient I'm talking about is $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(x,y)^2$. This is where I looked for an ideal of finite length since the aforementioned ring is Artinian.

Comment: Maybe I have to explain this better: we have a local ring $(R,\ m)$ and two primary ideals $q,q'$ with $q$ $p$-primary ($p\subsetneq m$) and $q'$ $m$-primary. We want an ideal of finite length in $R/q\cap q'$. This is certainly $q/q\cap q'$ since it's isomorphic to $(q+q')/q'$, an ideal of $R/q'$ which is an Artinian ring. (I should think a little more if this is indeed the largest ideal of finite length in $R/q\cap q'$.)

Comment: I can show now that $q/q\cap q'$ is the largest ideal of finite length in $R/q\cap q'$. Suppose $a/q\cap q'$ have finite length. Then the ring $R/\mathrm{Ann}_R(a/q\cap q')$ is Artinian. But $$\mathrm{Ann}_R(a/q\cap q')=(q\cap q'):a=(q:a)\cap(q':a).$$ If $a$ is not contained in any of the two primary ideals then $(q:a)\cap(q':a)$ is an intersection of two primary ideals, a contradiction. So $a\subseteq q$ or $a\subseteq q'$. In the first case we are done. In the second case $(q:a)\cap(q':a)=q:a$ which is $p$-primary, again a contradiction.

Comment: @user26857: Ah, that's very helpful.  Thanks!